# accepts_nested_attributes_for for edit api in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a paper model which has many questions. I am making api.

In paper.rb

```
 has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: :all_blank,allow_destroy: true
```

In question.rb

```
 belongs_to :paper
```

In paper_controller.rb

```
 def create
   paper = current_user.papers.create(paper_params)
   unless plan.blank?
     render json: {status: 'successful', paper: paper }, status: 201
   else
     render json: {error: 'Some thing went wrong'}, status: 401
   end
 end

 def update
   paper = Paper.find(params[:id])
   if paper.update_attributes(paper_params)
     render json: {status: 'successful', paper: paper }, status: 201
   else
     render json: {error: 'Some thing went wrong'}, status: 401
   end
 end

 private 

 def paper_params 
   params.require(:paper).permit(:subject,questions_attributes: [:id, :question])
 end
```

My problem is whenever I edit questions in a specific paper questions are not edited but new question are formed. For example If Have 3 questions and I have send request for edit then there will be 6 questions for that paper.

Comment: Are you sending `ID` of question in the `params` ? Can you show you `params` that is sent on `edit` action

Comment: Can you post your form code or at least the JSON body that your client is ending to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
For JSON there is a [known issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19254). More info [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17216).

---

If new questions are being formed it means your controller cannot find the existing child questions. The only way that could happen is if you are not sending the :id for each question, so the problem is not your controller or model, but what the form is sending from the client side.

If your form is using javascript, and submitting a json body, you should check also that the JSON structure has a child called "questions_attributes" and not "question_attributes".

FYI you do not need to actually specify the question :id in the permit code if your id's are integers (although you of course do have to send it for the update to work).

```
 def paper_params 
  params.require(:paper).permit(:id, :subject, questions_attributes: [:question])
 end
```

See the official docs example [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples). If your id's are not integers (eg. custom, such as GUIDS, then you do need it).